# svyolr "initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite"

Tags: r

I am running the svyolr (ordinal logistic regression model) and receiving this error message:

```
model_1_OLR <-svyolr (quality~patient, design=data1)


 Error in optim(s0, fmin, gmin, method = "BFGS", ...) : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

The factor variable looks like this

```
> levels(data$patient)
[1] "0" "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Any solutions to address this?